# what is difference between "binomial" and "binomial(link="logit")"?

Tags: logistic-regression, glmnet, binomial-coefficients

I tried the following glmnet code and got differnt coefficient results.
In the glmnet, doesn't "binomial" basically mean logit??
I wonder why the results are different.

clf<-cv.glmnet(X_train, fa_train, family=binomial, alpha=1, nlambda=100,
standardize=TRUE, type.measure="auc")

clf2<-cv.glmnet(X_train, fa_train, family=binomial(link="logit"), alpha=1, nlambda=100,
standardize=TRUE, type.measure="auc")